# Hive - Using Lateral View Explode with Joined Table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am building some analysis and need to prep the date by joining two tables and then unpivot a date field and create one record for each "date_type". I have been trying to work with lateral view explode(array()) function but I can't figure out how to do this with columns from two separate tables. Any help would be appreciated, open to completely different methods.

TableA:

| loan_number | app_date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 07/09/2022 |
| 456 | 07/11/2022 |

TableB:

| loan_number | funding_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 08/13/2022 | 12000 |
| 456 | 08/18/2022 | 10000 |

Desired Result:

| loan_number | date_type | date_value | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | app_date | 07/09/2022 | 12000 |
| 456 | app_date | 07/11/2022 | 10000 |
| 123 | funding_date | 08/13/2022 | 12000 |
| 456 | funding_date | 08/18/2022 | 10000 |

Here is some sample code related the example above I was trying to make work:

```
SELECT
    b.loan_number,
    b.amount,
    Date_Value
    
FROM TableA as a
    LEFT JOIN 
    TableB as b
        ON a.loan_number=b.loan_number
    LATERAL VIEW explode(array(to_date(a.app_date),to_date(b.funding_date)) Date_List AS Date_value
```

Comment: "ISO 2014, though superseded, is the standard that originally introduced the all-numeric date notation in most-to-least-significant order [YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need `lateral view explode`, just `union`, try below:

```
with base_data as (
select
    a.loan_number,
    a.app_date,
    b.funding_date,
    b.amount
from
    tableA a 
join
    tableB b on a.loan_number = b.loan_number
) 
select
    loan_number,
    'app_date'  as date_type,
    app_date    as date_value,
    amount
from
    base_data
union all
select
    loan_number,
    'funding_date'  as date_type,
    funding_date    as date_value,
    amount
from
    base_data
```